# how to execute init scripts from the command line using ssh

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, unix, ssh

```
ssh -t user@server1 "ls -al /root/test/"
```

Above mentioned code works fine and displays all the contents of the test directory folder but this code fails

```
ssh -t user@server1 "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
```

It does not start the mysql server, I have login in to server and use the same command to start the mysql server

Can any one explain this behaviour ? what I am doing wrong bit puzzled :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

`ssh user@hostname "/etc/init.d/mysql start < /dev/null > /tmp/log 2>&1 &"`

ssh needs to use stdin and stdout to interact. This will allow it to do that and redirect the output to somewhere useful.

Comment: ssh -t provides the puedo terminal for interaction

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about roots of this behaviour, probably because ssh allocates pseudo-terminal. However you can use workaround with sudo:

```
ssh -t user@server1 "sudo service mysql start"
```

Comment: it's strange, what OS do have? I tested on RedHat 7

Comment: I am using centos 6.4 and maria db 10.0.17 installation. I did  not tried further try to investigate why it did not work after using this command ssh user@hostname "/etc/init.d/mysql start < /dev/null > /tmp/log 2>&1 &"